# Bind an ObservableDictionary in WPF xaml file

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I had an `ObservableCollection<MyDataType>`object named `myCollection` that I was presenting in a GUI using a `<DataTemplate>` in my `.XAML`file (See code below).
But now the type of `myCollection` has changed to a `Dictionary<UInt64,MyDataType>`.
How would I present it now? [Here](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/shimmy/archive/2010/12/26/observabledictionary-lt-tkey-tvalue-gt-c.aspx) I found an implementation of an `ObservableDictionary<>`. But I don't know how I would bind this to my GUI?
Thank you for any assistance!

```
<Page x:Class="Project.ThisPage"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
  xmlns:local="clr-ThisPage.ProjectSpace" 
  mc:Ignorable="d" 
  d:DesignHeight="480" d:DesignWidth="640"
Title="ThisPage"
  Name="thisPage">
    <Page.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="MyDataTemplate" DataType="{x:Type local:MyDataType}">
        <Label Content="{Binding Name}"/>
        <Label Content="{Binding Id}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Page.Resources>

<Grid>
 <ScrollViewer>
            <StackPanel>
                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=thisPage,Path=myCollection}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MyDataTemplate}" />
            </StackPanel>
 </ScrollViewer>
</Grid></Page>
```

Answer (score 0):

`myCollection.Values` will give you MyDataType collection and `myCollection.Keys` will give you UINT64 collection. So bind to MyDataType collection just update binding like:

```
ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=thisPage,Path=myCollection.Values}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MyDataTemplate}" />
```

Comment: I tried, but end up with an error `System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'myCollection' property not found on 'object' ''ThisPage' (Name='thisPage')'. BindingExpression:Path=myCollection.Values; DataItem='ThisPage' (Name='thisPage'); target element is 'ItemsControl' (Name=''); target property is 'ItemsSource' (type 'IEnumerable')`

Comment: Make sure that DataContext of your Page is property set and then ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=thisPage,Path=DataContext.myCollection.Values}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MyDataTemplate}" />. This is funny coz it should fail also when you tried with Collection instead of dictionary.

Comment: How do I set the DataContext properly?

Comment: where do you have myCollection property? in code behind of ThisPage?